# Does OpenSSL support ciphers with block size 512 bits?

Tags: encryption, openssl, encryption-symmetric

I added my own cipher as an engine to OpenSSL. My cipher supports different key sizes and block sizes, one of them is 512 bit block size. Does OpenSSL support ciphers with that key size and block size ?

When I set my cipher's block size to 64, this is what i get when i encrypt or decrypt:
The error is in evp_enc.c line 216
OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: ctx->cipher->block_size == 1 || ctx->cipher->block_size == 8 || ctx->cipher->block_size == 16

Does this mean that only these block sizes are supported in OpenSSL ?

Thanks.